# html agility how to process table in a hyperlink

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am working to get some information from a html table which has many rows like this. The given row is like one piece of info in a table cell. I need to get link, artist name, artist type from this table.

```
<a href="http://somesite/music/view_album.php?albumid=6468" style="color:#000;" sl-processed="1">
        <table width="100%" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

        <tbody><tr>
          <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top" style="color:#900;">album title</td>
          </tr>
        <tr> <td width="31%" align="left" valign="top">                         <img src="./albums_files/No_cover.png" width="90" height="80" border="0">  
        </td>
          <td width="69%" align="left" valign="top">
          <a class="leftcat" href="http://somelink/toartiset" sl-processed="1">       <strong>Rizwan-Muazzam</strong>
           </a>
          <br>
        (<a class="leftcat" href="http://linktoartisttype/" sl-processed="1">
        Some  Artist Type </a>) <br>
        <span class="leftcat">
        Rated +: 0<br>
        Rated -: 0          </span>

           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> <td valign="top" align="center" colspan="2">  
       </td> </tr>
      </tbody></table>
 </a>
```

I have done this

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(albumUrl);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
```

this gives me all the links which I need, now I want to get all the child information under the hyperlink.

Help will be appreciated.

Regards

Parminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a loop to go through all the rows and then select the links and extract the info from them:

```
var rows = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var links = row.SelectNodes(".//a");
    var artistLink = links[0].Attributes["href"];
    var artistName = links[0].SelectSingleNode(".//strong/text()").InnerText;

    var artistTypeLink = links[1].Attributes["href"];
    var artistTypeName = links[1].SelectSingleNode(".//text()").InnerText;

    // Store the results...
}
```